# Ocelot Proxy AddJsonFile reloadOnChange is not working on azure linux app service

Tags: .net-core, proxy, azure-web-app-service, ocelot

I am working with **Ocelot proxy**, I have a problem with **reloadOnChange** on azure **linux app service**. When changing the json configuration, they are not reflected until restarting the app service.

It working fine locally and when trying it on an azure **windows app service**.

The code I am using is

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile($"ocelot.json", false, true);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a walkaround to solve this problem as mentioned in the below urls

[kubernetes-reload-your-aspnet-core](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2021/03/kubernetes-reload-your-aspnet-core.html)

[ConfigMapFileProvider](https://github.com/fbeltrao/ConfigMapFileProvider)